# I am getting Verify error:66.29.141.51 while trying to verify SSL for a Domain

Tags: ssl, terminal, namecheap

i am using these commands to get free SSL certificate from namecheap -

```
# list all domains
$ ls 

#Get acme.sh utility
curl https://get.acme.sh | sh

#another
ls .acme.sh/

#Source the Environment variables
source ~/.bashrc

curl https://get.acme.sh | sh -s email=info@bikerackbrute.com
acme.sh --set-default-ca --server letsencrypt


#Register your email with Lets's Encrypt to be notified any renewals issue
acme.sh --register-account --accountemail info@bikerackbrute.com
acme.sh --debug 2 --register-account -m info@bikerackbrute.com --server letsencrypt

acme.sh --issue --webroot ~/public_html -d bikerackbrute.com --staging

acme.sh --issue --webroot ~/public_html -d bikerackbrute.com --force

.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d bikerackbrute.com -w /home/sokawhyb/bikerackbrute.com/

acme.sh --deploy --deploy-hook cpanel_uapi --domain bikerackbrute.com
```

But i am getting this error message -

```
[Tue Jul 11 02:11:04 EDT 2023] bikerackbrute.com:Verify error:66.29.141.51: Invalid response from http://bikerackbrute.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/fsPk0loScfPUHC8xD6jIWkUqscR38OB8gMymbIJqpyA: 404
```

I am trying to activate free SSL via namecheap terminal